# How can I disable an entire HTML page on an event like in the case of JavaScript alert?

Tags: jquery, css

I am developing a web page in JSP/HTML in which I have to disable/ 'gray screen' an entire web page on a button click event so that an end user can't access the other element in web page until it's disabled.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Do you mean something like a modal?

Comment: A layer on top. Example : http://fczaja.blogspot.in/2009/02/disable-all-page-elements-with.html

Comment: Use colorbox http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox

Answer (score 17):

CSS:

```css
#cover {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   opacity: 0.80;
   background: #aaa;
   z-index: 10;
   display: none;
}
```

HTML :

```
<body>
<div id="wrap">
 // your normal contents here
</div>
<div id="cover"> </div>
</body>
```

jquery :

```
//trigger on whatever event required.
$("#cover").fadeIn(100);
alert("something");
$("#cover").fadeOut(100); //after done.
```

Comment: But this doesn't block keyboard. You can still Tab & Enter to get button clicked.

Answer (score 8):

You may use **[jQuery BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/)** Plugin.

It is simple.

Answer (score 4):

There are may ways to achieve this..
but the simplest one which i came across is to use div tag 
to cover the page and then remove it when event is complete

```
$('body').append('<div id="over" style="position: absolute;top:0;left:0;width: 100%;height:100%;z-index:2;opacity:0.4;filter: alpha(opacity = 50)"></div>');
```

This will add a div tag to whole body.At the end of function include this

```
$("#over").remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can use JQuery, and need some user input on top the gray area, try [JQUery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), and set it as [modal](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/modal-form.html)

Answer (score 2):

The basic technique for this is to add a 100% width and height div on top of everything.

```
$('body').append('<div class="cover"/>').css({
    position: 'absolute',
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    zIndex: '999'
});
```

Then make your modal window `z-index: 1000`.