# How to disable screen in HTML which block user interactions?

Tags: html, css

I dunno how exactly I can explain my issue or if the title is specific enough.
But what I want to do is for example I have a game like Tic Tac Toe and if the game finish a message should pop up the entire screen which block any other interactions except there is a button only.
Like that:

[image]

I think something with `display: ???`

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36218066/how-to-make-the-splash-page-div-fade-after-being-clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive made a simple example for you how it could be done:

```
<head>
<style>
.content {
color: red;
}

.overlay {
  z-index: 1;
  width:100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  background-color:black;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.msg {
  background-color: white;
  width: 70px;
  padding: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align:center;
  position: absolute;
  top:40%;
  left: 45%;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="content">some content</p>
<div class=overlay>
<p class="msg">TEST</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

this shows a black overlay over the complete Screen with a "TEST"-Message, you can add more Items like Buttons to the "overlay"-div if you want to.

But keep in mind, to use the "position: absolute;" attribute.

You can show or hide it by setting the "display: none" (hide) css-attribute to the "overlay"-div or setting "display: revert;" to show it

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a fullscreen overlay. 
Link: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_fullscreen_overlay.asp
Then you can add a Javascript event so that your quiz restarts when the user clicks the restart button. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You might want to look at this post, [How can I disable an entire HTML page on an event like in the case of JavaScript alert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477267/how-can-i-disable-an-entire-html-page-on-an-event-like-in-the-case-of-javascript) I found it just by searching your question on Google. You'll probably need to use jquery for the solution.